# How to hide one series data info in tooltip using highcharts

Tags: highcharts, hide, legend, series

Hi I am getting a following chart:[image]

I want to hide the water info from the tooltip. How can I do that. You can use the following fiddle to play with it.

Thanks!!!

Comment: use this fiddle to play with it.:   http://jsfiddle.net/0zq3r2w4/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were almost there. You needed to check the api for the shared tooltip [formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter). Put your check for the series you do not want inside the for each:

```
...
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function () {
                    var s = '<b>' + this.x + '</b>';
                    $.each(this.points, function () {
                        if (this.series.name != 'Water') {
                            s += '<br/>' + this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + 'm';
                        }                       
                    });
                    return s;
                },
                shared: true,
                valueSuffix: ' cm'

            },
...
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to customize the tooltipfunction. just add this to the series object which should be hidden:

```
'tooltip'=> [
            'pointFormat'=> ''
          ]
```